# nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) even after killing the process using port 80

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm trying to start nginx as follows:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ which nginx
/usr/sbin/nginx
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Following this [EasyEngine tutorial](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/troubleshooting/emerg-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use/), I tried to kill the process using port 80 with `fuser -k`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
80/tcp:              31924 31925 31926
```

However, after re-running `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx` I get exactly the same error message.

I've tried a couple of other 'diagnostics' described [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-what-running-on-port-80-command/), using `fuser`, `lsof -i`, and `netstat`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ fuser 80/tcp
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ netstat -tulpn | grep --color :80
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Only the `netstat` command gives a result, but I wasn't able to infer a process ID from it.

Any ideas on how to get nginx to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should run this

```
user@user ~ $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep --color :80
```

it will show you process id

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2063/apache2
```

2063/apache2 – PID/Process name